# Compute approximate function change knowing x

Tags: derivatives

Compute approximate value of a function change
  $y=x^3 - x^2$ when $x=2$ and $\Delta x=0.01$. Any ideas how to solve it?

**My idea**
Let $Δx = dx$ and $Δy= dy$, then $f(x+Δx) = f(x) + f′(x)\timesΔx, \quad Δx = 2-0.01=1.99$, then $f(0,01) + f ′ (0,01) \times 1,99 = \ldots$

Am I right?

Comment: It is likely that you were given $\Delta x=0.01$ instead of $x=0.01$. The distance between $2$ and $0.01$ is relatively large. Therefore, an approximation using a Taylor polynomial of degree $1$ shouldn't be particularly good.

Comment: No. The excercise says x=2 and x=0,01. Then if it is not right what is correct solution.?

Comment: Any number is an approximation. Therefore, it is never going to be wrong. The question is how good it your approximation. In this case, since the function is just a polynomial, you could even compute the exact value. In every case, whoever gave you that problem has no idea how to formulate a problem properly.

Comment: Do you mean f ' (2) and f ' (0,01)?

Comment: The change of the function from $x=2$ to $x=0.01$ is $f(2)-f(0.01)$, which can be computed exactly in this case. The exact value is the best approximation.

Answer (score 0):

You get lost when you get to $\Delta x = 2-0.01=1.99$.

You are *given* that $\Delta x = 0.01$. It doesn't suddenly change to $1.99$.

The key realization is that $$f'(x) =\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$
so for small values of $\Delta x, f'(x) \approx \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$, and therefore $$f(x + \Delta x) - f(x) = \Delta y \approx f'(x)\Delta x\\f(x + \Delta x) \approx f(x) + f'(x)\Delta x$$

Now you are given that $x = 2, \Delta x = 0.01$ and $y = f(x) = x^3 - x^2$. So:
$$f(2) = 8 - 4 = 4\\f'(x) = 3x^2 - 2x\\f'(2) = 12 - 4 = 8$$

Plugging that in:
$$f(2 + 0.01) \approx 4 + 8 \times 0.01\\f(2.01) \approx 4.08$$

The actual value is $f(2.01) = 4.080501$, so the approximation is pretty good.

Comment: But it says when x=2 and x=0,01 it isnt sais that  $Δx = 0.01$

Comment: @tomaspak - right now (and when I posted), it says that $\Delta x = 0.01$. I answered the question I saw. I'm sorry if that isn't the question you originally posted. However, I very strongly suspect that your book also *intended* $\Delta x = 0.01$, and it was just a typo to say "$x = 0.01$".